# Import face_recognition by python on ubuntu

Tags: python, boost, face-recognition

I am trying to play around with face_recognition on python, but after I pip install the face_recognition module everytime I try to import face_recognition I get the following error messages:

> import face_recognition
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/face_recognition/**init**.py", line 7, in
>
> from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 4, in
>
> import dlib
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dlib/**init**.py", line 1, in
>
> from .dlib import *
>
> ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I don't know what could be causing the trouble. Any help is appreciated! I believe It has to do with the shared file in the last line of the error message, though I don't have any clues as to where it is located :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Boost.Python? Try `apt-get install libboost-python-dev` on Debian-likes.

Ah, but I see on [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libboost-python-dev) and [Debian testing](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libboost-all-dev) that that is only at version 1.62, and it seems that your module specifically requires version 1.64 — which was released less than two months ago.

Most distributions do not seem to have available for Boost 1.64, so if you need that version specifically, you may have to build it from source. There are some instructions in the [Boost.Python docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/building.html).